# How to show design .btw in the form using C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a design for bar code label, then show on the form before printing this label. I found how to screenshot,  but I cannot show the label design, and I tried to paint it using bitmap and I failed also in that. 
Any advice?

This is how to screenshot:

```
public static void CaptureAndSave(int x, int y, int width, int height, string imagePath)
{
   try
   {
      Bitmap myImage = ScreenShot.Capture(x, y, width, height);
      myImage.Save(@"D:\" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea, what exactly is your problem. You talk about bar code label, then printing, then screenshot. Please be specific about your question (and ask only one question at a time).

Comment: How about https://github.com/SourceCodeBackup/GenCode128

Comment: i need to show my barcode-design.btw as an image on the form